# How to get notified of Windows process maximizing CPU?

Tags: windows, performance, utilities

Is there a tool for Windows XP and Vista (built-in or otherwise ideally freeware/[OSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source_software)) that can notify the user when the CPU is above a (configurable) threshold for some (configurable) duration?

I am particularly interested in a *minimalist* tool that fits the following bill and in order of importance (which a lot of the built-in Windows facilities like [Performance/Resource Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx) do not):

1. Does not require administrative privileges
2. Has a *low working set* so it has no observable cost if left running forever
3. Monitors silently in the system tray
4. Uses a subtle (not in-your-face) notification method like showing a balloon tip with the name of the offending process that has been maximizing the CPU
5. Can be configured to start automatically when a user logs on interactively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [ProcessTamer](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/proctamer/index.html) could be helpfull. It does not exactly what you are look for. But it might be a quick and dirty solution.

> Process Tamer is a tiny (140k) and super efficient utility for Microsoft Windows XP/2K/NT that runs in your system tray and constantly monitors the cpu usage of other processes. When it sees a process that is overloading your cpu, it reduces the priority of that process temporarily, until its cpu usage returns to a reasonable level.
>
> [image: Screenshot]
>   <sub>(source: [donationcoder.com](https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/proctamer/screenshots/pt.png))</sub>

Comment: This seems to come pretty close and definitely worth knowing about. The One big downside, however, is that it requires administrative privileges, which fails the first bill.

Comment: Until a better suggestion comes along later, I'm going to consider this as a pretty close answer (fits bills 2-5) for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own utility.

Here a sample as starter:
http://gist.github.com/11658

1. Create a CpuMeter instance
2. ResetCounter
3. Wait for an intervall
4. Check Cpu utilisation
5. Start again

Comment: The quoted sample seems to come from Ingo Rammer's blog: http://blogs.thinktecture.com/ingo/archive/2004/06/22/414043.aspx